# Installation error on gocart

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get these  Error While install the GoCart .
But database was filled with the required tables of GoCart

**The /projects/GoCart/gocart/config/ folder is not writable! This is required to generate the config files.**

**The root folder is not writable! This is required if you want to eliminate "index.php" from the URL by generating an .htaccess file.**

Answer (score 0):

Like other installable softwares (ordpress & Opencart), it seems that even goCart generates the config files on the fly. Below are few options to solve your problem.

1. Create/edit the config files manually. Config files mostly hold details like base url of your project, DB credentials to connect to, encryption key etc which you can manually enter.
2. Make the config folder world writable by 755/777 command and once the installation is completed, decrease the permission back to 644
3. Give apache(www-data) the entire access to your GoCart folder so that apache can    create/modify the files